# Как добавить поле к выдаче в зависимости от того находится ли запись в другой таблице?

Tags: mysql

Как получать данные из таблицы А и добавлять к ним переменную 'c' со значением, в зависимости от того, находится ли данная запись в другой таблице В.

```
select
  a.*, 
  (CASE
    WHEN
      b.one_id = a.one_id
      AND b.two_id = a.two_id
      AND b.three_id = a.three_id
    THEN
      true
    ELSE
      false
  END) AS c
from a, b;
```

Делаю так, а мне выдаются намного больше записей чем имеется и при этом они повторяются.

Comment: Причины такого поведения не знаю, но в таких случаях обычно помогает GROUP BY a.id

Comment: @alexeich, в данном случае проблема в том, что не указано по какому условию соединяются таблицы, поэтому первая строка `a` соединяется последовательно со всеми строками из `b`, затем вторая строка `a` соединяется со всеми строками из `b` и т.д. Т.е. простой `group by` здесь не поможет

Comment: Кстати, я не знаю какая у вас версия MySQL, но выборка из нескольких таблиц через from - такой синтаксис считается устаревшим. И лучше юзать join'ы.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line

Answer (score 1):

Какой-то странный у вас запрос. Судя по всему нужно так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ce03/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table a (
  one_id int,
  two_id int,
  three_id int,
  _comment text
  );

  create table b (
  one_id int,
  two_id int,
  three_id int
  );

  insert into a (one_id,two_id,three_id,_comment)
  values 
  (1,1,1,'я есть в b'),
  (1,2,2,'и я есть в b'),
  (1,3,3,'и я тоже есть в b'),
  (4,4,4,'меня нет в b'),
  (5,5,5,'меня тоже нет в b');

  insert into b (one_id,two_id,three_id)
  values 
  (1,1,1),
  (1,2,2),
  (1,3,3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select a.*, b.one_id is not null as c
from a left join b on 
  b.one_id = a.one_id
  AND b.two_id = a.two_id
  AND b.three_id = a.three_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ce03/1/0)**:

```
| one_id | two_id | three_id |          _comment | c |
|--------|--------|----------|-------------------|---|
|      1 |      1 |        1 |        я есть в b | 1 |
|      1 |      2 |        2 |      и я есть в b | 1 |
|      1 |      3 |        3 | и я тоже есть в b | 1 |
|      4 |      4 |        4 |      меня нет в b | 0 |
|      5 |      5 |        5 | меня тоже нет в b | 0 |
```

Comment: Тут ведь выведет только те, которые есть во второй таблице. А мне нужно вывести все и добавить переменную `с` равную 1 или 0 при условии, что запись имеется во второй таблице.

Comment: @ArtieLay, вы с чего взяли что выведет только те, что есть во второй? Вы этот запрос проверяли? Он выполняет ровно то, что вы хотите. Вы плохо понимаете как работает mysql, советую почитать книжки хотя бы для начинающих

Comment: @BOPOH, да, я собирался почитать, просто сейчас очень нужно сделать. я разобрался как. А запрос выше я проверил, мне вроде как вывело записи которые только и там и там есть.

Comment: @ArtieLay обновил ответ. никаких "вроде как".